# Errors when repairing ext4 filesystem

Tags: linux, lvm, ext4

I just tried to boot from live CD and checked my file system using `fsck`,`fsck.ext4`, no errors was reported/fixed (i.e. says file system is clean), yet when I'm inside of system it tells me something else:

```
[alexus@XXXXXXXX Desktop]$ sudo fsck.ext4 -n /dev/mapper/vg_wcmisdlin02a-lv_root 
[sudo] password for alexus: 
e2fsck 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Warning!  /dev/mapper/vg_wcmisdlin02a-lv_root is mounted.
Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
/dev/mapper/vg_wcmisdlin02a-lv_root contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Deleted inode 3014659 has zero dtime.  Fix? no

Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.  Fix? no

Inode 3014660 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 3014661 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Block bitmap differences:  -(6391833--6391836)
Fix? no

Free blocks count wrong for group #195 (32313, counted=32309).
Fix? no

Free blocks count wrong (51472641, counted=51472559).
Fix? no

Inode bitmap differences:  -(3014659--3014661)
Fix? no

Free inodes count wrong for group #432 (8138, counted=8139).
Fix? no

Free inodes count wrong (14479710, counted=14479581).
Fix? no


/dev/mapper/vg_wcmisdlin02a-lv_root: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********

/dev/mapper/vg_wcmisdlin02a-lv_root: 233122/14712832 files (0.2% non-contiguous), 7346943/58819584 blocks
[alexus@XXXXXX Desktop]$
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you're running this against a device that is mounted read/write.

Don't do that.  You will get errors.  Remount it read-only. If it's a critical system filesystem like / (which this appears to be), then boot to single user mode and mount it read-only.  You likely have writes to that device in-flight that haven't fully flushed to the block device.

```
root@backup ~:
# mount /dev/JBOD/test /mnt
root@backup ~:
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/bigfile bs=1M count=2048
2048+0 records in
2048+0 records out
2147483648 bytes (2.1 GB) copied, 1.41783 s, 1.5 GB/s
root@backup ~:
# fsck.ext4 -fn /dev/JBOD/test
e2fsck 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Warning!  /dev/JBOD/test is mounted.
Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Free inodes count wrong (327669, counted=327668).
Fix? no


/dev/JBOD/test: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********

/dev/JBOD/test: 11/327680 files (0.0% non-contiguous), 55902/1310720 blocks
root@backup~:
# mount -o remount,ro /mnt
root@backup ~:
# fsck.ext4 -fn /dev/JBOD/test
e2fsck 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Warning!  /dev/JBOD/test is mounted.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/JBOD/test: 12/327680 files (0.0% non-contiguous), 580191/1310720 blocks
```

Your filesystem probably is clean.

Comment: I _DID_ boot into a single mode w/ Live CD and as I said before it did _NOT_ report any issues, so that's why it was weird that it's reporting issues once I'm inside of the system, not to mention every reboot I make fsck suppose to checks everything anyway)